# Redirect wordpress site to homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I would like to redirect my WordPress website to the homepage

For example, when the user goes to the following address

mywebsite.com

It will redirect to

mywebsite.com/homepage

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Go to** `Administration > Settings > Reading panel`.
2. Set **Front page displays** to a **static page**
3. In the drop down menu for **Front Page** select "Home."
4. In the drop down menu for **Posts page** select "Blog" or the name you
   created, or leave it blank if you will not feature posts on the
   site.
5. Save changes.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> Usage of Redirection plugin will do the trick for you. and It is one of the very Easiest method.

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Install this plugin and you will find the settings page and you can provide the URL over to there.

After Installation of the Plugin it will appear on Tools Menu under the Admin Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess :

> RewriteRule mywebsite.com$ mywebsite.com/homepage [R=301,L]